# It was a family affair rather than a parochial one

Tags: meaning

What does mean "parochial "?

It was a family affair rather than a parochial one.

Comment: Do you have the ability to  look up words in a dictionary? We are not a dictionary service.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From Oxford:

> Relating to a Church parish.

In this context, it's an affair limited to the family rathen than the entire district

Comment: in this one "The less our representatives are bound to the demands of nationhood, the less parochial their outlook is likely to be" means "Relating to a Church parish"  also?

Comment: Less parochial in this case means not limited, less confined to the district where the representatives live, not related to Church

Comment: In the UK, a parish is the smallest unit of local government as well as the area served by a local church.